# Click() does not complete

Tags: selenium, webdriver, autoit

### Steps

1. Click on the Browse button in Firefox
2. Opens a window dialogue (Browse for a file)
3. Choose the file (AutoIt script)

### Java code

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();
    String path = "C:\\FileUpload.Av3.exe";
    driver.findElement(By.xpath (")).click(); - Browse Button in Web application

    try {
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path); - Execute AutoIT .exe file
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

### Working

1. Put a breakpoint in line 2 of the Java code and
2. comment line 3 and
3. click on Browse button and
4. continue execution after clicking manually

This works fine with AutoIt.

### Not working

After line 3 the execution will not continue and the controls are not passed back from Firefox to Selenium.

Answer (score 4):

Selenium WebDriver cannot handle it. Use `sendKeys` to insert the local path to the file in the File Input element:

```
String path = "C:\FileUpload.Av3.exe";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/path/to/the/file/input/element")).sendKeys(path);
```

Please see [FAQ docs of Selenium WebDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Does_WebDriver_support_file_uploads?).

Comment: I did try this but the just if u click on the text box it opens the browse window

Comment: Do not click on the text box at all. You need to find the file input element that looks like this:
    <input type="file" ...>
This is the element you need to use sendKeys to send the file path to. WebDriver CANNOT interact with the Browse dialog box, so when this appears, WebDriver cannot continue.

Comment: <TD><Label>File:</Label></TD> <td class="spaceUnder"><Input id="" type ="File name="file_0"></td>. This is all we have for the element when i highlight this it highlights both textbox and button as single element.

Comment: ok, so find your element by something like this: driver.findElement(By.xpath("input[@type='File']").sendKeys(path);

Answer (score 0):

Remove try-catch block and use only the below code. Let me know if it is working.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath (")).click(); - Browse Button in Web application
String path = "C:\\FileUpload.Av3.exe";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path); - Execute AutoIT .exe file
```

Comment: this is not happening i have tried this. after this line "driver.findElement(By.xpath (")).click();" the webdriver does not go to the next line in code. But if the close the window which is opened for browsing the file , the execution goes to next line.

Comment: It does not even go to the line where the AutoIT code is called. It stops after I click the browse button. I used Robot Class also it is not executing any statement after clicking browse button.

Answer (score 0):

The Click call is a blocking call, which does not return until the page is loaded.  Since the click opens a dialog box, the click will not return until the dialog box is closed.

To get around this, call Click in a seperate thread, and then call the AutoIt script.  Once the AutoIt script closes the dialog box, the click will return, and the rest of your test can continue.

Comment: Sorry to have not picked your answer till now. can you please explian how can i do this i am not expert in java. This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue after clicking on "Download Excel" link. To fix this issue, I used `JavascriptExecutor` to get execution control back.

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```